# Update parent knockout observable array items when one of the observable inside array changes

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, closures, knockout-3.0

I basically have an observable array in my ViewModel

```
self.details=ko.observableArray([]);
```

which holds an array of model - DetailModel which has an `isChecked` property as an observable.

I want to subscribe to changes to `isChecked` and remove all other checkbox checks.

```
for(var i=0;i<10;++i)
{
    var detail=new DetailModel(i);

    detailList.push(detail);
    detail.isChecked.subscribe(function(checkBoxCheckedState){

    if(checkBoxCheckedState==true)
    {
      /* Idea is to untick all other checkboxes if one is checked */
      console.log(detail);
      console.log(detailList);
      ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.details(), function(detailRow) {
          if(detailRow.id!=detail.id)
          {
              detailRow.isChecked(false);
          }
      });
    }
});
```

I am initializing the details array inside a loop and attaching the subscribe there, because of closure, only the last detail object is available inside the subscribe function.

How can I achieve the same without passing callback to parent /  parent model reference inside child view model?

https://jsfiddle.net/7srbxu5y/17/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you really need `isChecked` in the detail model? Could you consider using just one `selected` property in the parent view model instead? In this case your child models would not have to know anything about parent viewmodel. See sample code

```
function DetailModel(name) {
   this.name = name;
}

function ViewModel(items) {
    this.items = ko.observableArray(items);    
    this.selected = ko.observable();
}

ViewModel.prototype.select = function select(data) {
   var selected = this.selected.peek();
   if (selected !== data) {
        this.selected(data);
   } else {   
        this.selected(null);
   }
   return true;
}
```

[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mbrodin/koynhvsw/1/)

Comment: i thought of this, it is possible,thanks. How can we make it so that a subscribe can work inside a loop? I know it has something to do with closures. Any thoughts? I would like to try that as well, to understand